# Sexual joke/pun with メスブタ and オスブタ

Tags: meaning, puns, metaphor, jokes

Context: a boxer has a lot of female fans that worship him because of his handsomeness. They call him 王子. His trainer is a pervert who likes to receive anal sex from women with sex toys. In an extra scene at the end of the manga, the boxer and his trainer meet a female fan that hands him a lipstick and a paper sheet saying:

> この**メスブタ**めに〝お恵み〟を与えて頂けないでしょうか…

The boxer rubs the lipstick on his lips and kisses the paper sheet. Then he says:

> **欲しがりなブタ**は嫌いじゃあない

After this, the trainer takes the lipstick and asks:

> この**オスブタ**めの〝穴〟に恵みをくださ〜〜い♡　ミストレス

1) What is the meaning of メスブタ and オスブタ in this context? I know they are the female and male of the pig, but do they have  a metaphorical meaning here?

2) What is the め after メスブタ and オスブタ?

3) What is the meaning of 欲しがりなブタ? How does ブタ as a suffix work?

4) Why is it じゃあない and not じゃない in the second sentence?

Here's [the original page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wX82.jpg). Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:**

I found [here](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E9%9B%8C%E8%B1%9A) this definition of メスブタ:

> SMプレイ時に興奮度を高めるなどの目的で、サディスト側がマゾヒスト側へ投げかける言葉の一つ。

But still, why does she call herself メスブタ？

Comment: If you don't show your own research, your question may get closed.

Comment: For #2, this will be of help.. → https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23518/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. メスブタ is used when people insult women. This オスブタ is a parody of メスブタ.
2. め is used when people insult something or themselves.
3. It means "a pig that covets anything", and it is similar to 欲張り.
4. We sometimes write phrases with emphasis on vowel like that. 嫌いではない、嫌いじゃない and 嫌いじゃあない are the same meaning, and they are more casual in decreasing order.

As for your last question, it is because she effaced herself in front of the person she worshipped. This whole coversation is SM-ish.