# What does "め" mean in this case?

Tags: suffixes

In the book I'm reading, a boy is looking for a tomato, he says "トマトめトマトめ どこ行ったの". What does "め" mean in this case?

Comment: The sentence doesn't sound super natural as today's Japanese. Could you provide the whole paragraph or so for the context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Meaning behind adding 'め' after someone's name?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23515/9831)

Answer (score 8):

め can be a pejorative suffix attached to nouns. It adds a negative meaning or emphasis of insult to that word.

[This site](http://www.sf.airnet.ne.jp/%7Ets/japanese/message/jpnE2lki6zwE2d_2qW-.html) shows a couple examples:

> **馬鹿め!** (Bakame!/You idiot!)

Hence you could translate the sentence as: "*Stupid tomato, stupid tomato! Where'd you go!*". It is also a personification of that tomato, since the boy is addressing his tomato directly.

[Some](https://jref.com/threads/dishonorifics-question.34315/) forum users use the word "dishonorific", but it doesn't seem to be a word that is generally accepted, known, or relevant.

As Eiríkr Útlendi pointed out in the comments, the correct term for the process of a neutral word becoming "rude" is called pejoration ("make worse"). The word itself is then called a pejorative. Pejoration is applied to トマト through the attachment of the [pejorative suffix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pejorative_suffix) め.  Another way to call it is "derogatory suffix".

Comment: I think “pejorative” is more widely used and understood than “dishonorific”.

Comment: jisho.org describes [奴/め](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%A5%B4-2) as "derogatory suffix", which I think would also be a fitting description.

Comment: I added that possible definition